# AWS DynamoDB Java BatchWriteItem Connect Reset error

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection reset
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:324)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:164)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:985)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodb.AmazonDynamoDBClient.batchWriteItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:365)
    .
    .
    .
```

The above exception was caught when attempting to run the following [code sample](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/batch-operation-lowlevel-java.html).

```
BatchWriteItemResult result;
BatchWriteItemRequest batchWriteItemRequest = new BatchWriteItemRequest();
do {
    System.out.println("Making the request.");                         
    batchWriteItemRequest.withRequestItems(requestItems);
    result = client.batchWriteItem(batchWriteItemRequest);

    // Print consumed capacity units
    for(Map.Entry<String, BatchWriteResponse> entry : result.getResponses().entrySet()) {
        String tableName = entry.getKey();
        Double consumedCapacityUnits = entry.getValue().getConsumedCapacityUnits();
        System.out.println("Consumed capacity units for table " + tableName + ": " + consumedCapacityUnits);
     }

  // Check for unprocessed keys which could happen if you exceed provisioned throughput
    System.out.println("Unprocessed Put and Delete requests: \n" + result.getUnprocessedItems());
    requestItems = result.getUnprocessedItems();
} while (result.getUnprocessedItems().size() > 0);
```

I have 1 table set up with 8 Write Units configured.

In my `BatchWriteItemRequest` I have 9 `PutRequestItems`.

When the first time in the while loop, 8 out of the 9 PutRequestItems were processed.
Therefore, the loop was entered again, trying to process the one remaining request.

However, the code would hang at 
`result = client.batchWriteItem(batchWriteItemRequest);` for around 149 seconds. After then, the above mentioned exception is thrown.

It seems the only way to bypass this was to set a higher Write Provisioning Unit. However, isn't the while-do loop a way to handle cases where we exceed our provisioned Write Units?

Comment: How big are the 9 items you attempt to store ? Did you check there was no outage where you ran the request ?

Comment: Each of them has got 9 fields, the biggest field is a String filed with about less than 100 characters.

Comment: I don't believe there was an outage, since 1, the first 8/9 items were written to the db in no time; 2, all 9 items were written as soon as I turn my Write Unit over 9 from the Dynamo Admin Console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug on the Java Driver v. 1.3.21 (or maybe including older versions).

1.3.21.1 was released just to take care of that:

> Resolved Issues
>
> SocketException During Request Retries
>
> Fixes an issue where retries caused by service error responses (i.e.
>   not IO error retries) aren't able to correctly resend the request
>   payload for services like Amazon DynamoDB that utilize request
>   payloads.

see http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/Java/5659251433242996

Answer (score 0):

There was one release of the AWS SDK for Java which broke retry behavior in the way you're describing.  Basically, the input stream for the request wasn't getting reset between attempts, so each retry would immediately fail.  DynamoDB does 10 retries with exponential backoff by default, resulting in the very long delays that you saw.  Update your SDK to get around this issue:

http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/

Comment: Thanks. However, we've switch to use MongoDB several weeks ago. I would be happy to test with the new SDK and post my results here.